# Comparar dos columnas de una tabla en RStudio con prop.test

Tags: r, tidyverse

Estoy tratando de comparar dos columnas de una tabla para calcular el valor de p con prop.test, obtendo el siguiente error:

> tab1$`P-value`[4] <- signif(with(vl.dat, prop.test(x = table(vac_label, treat_group)))$p.value, 3)
> Error in prop.test(x = table(vac_label, treat_group)) :
> 'x' must have 2 columns

mis dos columnas son vac_label, treat_group, no entiendo por qué me dice que no hay dos columnas.

Gracias!

Comment: ¡Hola @tasmarquez! Para poderte ayudar es necesario que pongas un ejemplo de los datos que utilizas (pueden ser ficticios) y con los que te de el error. Si no, es complicado poder determinar qué ocurre.